For an organization's private repository used as a dependency how to reference token outside of package.json?
Not wanting to store a secret in the package.json I'm trying to find the correct way to pass a secret for an organization repository as a dependency. If I reference the dependency:
"dependencies": {
  "@org/repo": "git+https://<REPO_TOKEN>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/org/repo.git",
},

and I've created a .npmrc file with:
 - name: Create .npmrc
    run: echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${{ secrets.REPO_TOKEN }}" >> .npmrc

created a root .env file with the token:
REPO_TOKEN=blahBlah

and when I run yarn I get the error message if:

Error: Failed to replace env in config: ${{ secrets.REPO_TOKEN }

In my user account settings I created the token from Developer Settings > Personal access tokens > Tokens (classic). Gave it the select scope settings of everything in repo:

Navigated back to the repo in the org I'm trying to pull in the dependency and navigated to Settings > Secrets and variables > Actions > Repository secrets and created a New repository secret named REPO_TOKEN.
Research:

Install an npm module from a private GitHub repository using GitHub Actions
npm install private github repositories by dependency in package.json

In an organizations repository I'm developing how can I use another organizations repository as a dependency without storing the secret as text in the package.json?

You can use a Makefile for that:
include .env
export $(shell sed 's/=.*//' .env)

replace:
    sed -i 's/REPO_TOKEN/$(REPO_TOKEN)/g' package.json

Here we are importing the env file and exporting all the variables from it to the environment, included REPO_TOKEN. Lastly, we declare the command in which we call replace.
With .env file and the Makefile done, you can use the command make replace to run the action. Normally Jenkins file is used for that where you can use as a script in one of the stages of deploy pipeline:
pipeline {
  ...,
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      agent any
      steps {
        script {
          sh 'make replace'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  ...,
}

